# How do I write a correct [HttpGet] Update method in .Net Core 6 with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Below code is my AutoMapper profile:

```
    CreateMap<Product, UpdateProductViewModel>().ReverseMap().ForMember(x => x.Categories,     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Categories.Select(x => x.Text.ToString()).ToList()));
```

Below is my [HttpGet] Update method that throws an exception:

```
    [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult UpdateProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = _service.GetProductById(id);
            var mappedProduct = _mapper.Map<UpdateProductViewModel>(product);
            return View(mappedProduct);
        }
```

Here is an exception when I click edit to update the object:

```
  AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error mapping types.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Does anyone have a clue on what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Have you added `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));` in `program.cs`?

Comment: This is what I did on my Program.cs class `var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Install `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` nuget package and configure `AutoMapper` like described in the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html).

```cs
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
```